# Move static positioned element left by arbitrary amount of pixels

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a Bootstrap 4 navbar and added a left-border of a different color for design purposes.

This has the unforunate side-effect of causing the container of the navbar to not be lined up with the container of the main content.

I'm trying to offset the inner container 80px to compensate for the border, but when I try adjusting the position it obviously messes up the rest of the layout.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style>
    .navbar {
        border-left: 80px solid red;
    }

    .navbar .container {
        left: 80px; /* something like this */
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand"
                    href="/">Site</a>

                <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed"
                    type="button"
                    data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#mainMenu"
                    aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault"
                    aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="icon-bar top-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar middle-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar bottom-bar"></span>
                </button>


                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"
                    id="mainMenu">

                    <div class="form-inline ml-auto">
                        <label class="sr-only"
                            for="search-text">Search</label>
                        <div class="input-group mr-2 mb-2 mb-sm-0">
                            <input type="text"
                                class="form-control"
                                id="search-text"
                                placeholder="search...">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <a href="/search/"
                                    type="button"
                                    id="search-button"
                                    class="btn btn-light">
                                    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a href="/account/login"
                            class="btn btn-outline-light">log in</a>
                        <a href="/account/signup"
                            class="btn btn-info ml-2">sign up</a>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="container">
            <ol class="breadcrumb my-4">

                <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Bread crumbs</li>

            </ol>
            <h1>and some content</h1>

        </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/kalenpw/pen/YzwxENZ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `padding-right: 80px;` to `.navbar` to push it back.

Comment: Awesome that worked! I thought that would add a horizontal scroll, bu it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood correctly but you can try:

```css
.navbar {
  border-left: 80px solid red;
}

.navbar .container {
  left: 80px; /* something like this */
  margin-left:0px !important
}
```

Comment: I tried that already, but it causes the navbar to not be centered